# setValuesForKeysWithDictionary in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, key-value-coding, keypaths

It seems like Swift 4 is implementing different method to `(void)setValuesForKeysWithDictionary()`, what is appropriate replacement to this function in Swift 4?

I have struct of

```
struct User {
    let name: String?
    let email: String?
}
```

The `dictionaryOfUsers` is coming from data structure which value are presented dynamically based on the number of users in the database:

```
let dictionaryOfUsers = [{key1: "name1", key2 : "name1@xyz.com"}, {key1 : "name2", key2 : "name2@gmail.com"} ]   
let users = [User]
```

Now I want to use this function to create my user array to create dictionary in Swift 4:

```
for dictionary in dictionaryOfUsers {
    let user = User()
    user.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
```

and append to users

```
    users.append(user)
}
```

Comment: What `key1` and `key2` stand for? I expected `”name”` and ‘`”email”` strings instead...

Comment: yes key1 and key2 are for "name " and "email"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this method instead:

```
func setValuesForKeys(_ keyedValues: [String : Any])
```

> Sets properties of the receiver with values from a given dictionary, using its keys to identify the properties. The default implementation invokes `setValue(_:forKey:)` for each key-value pair[...](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1417515-setvaluesforkeys)

Your code has many minor issues — and some major issues as well (see *matt* answer for more info). Anyway, I think this should accomplish what you are after:

```
import Foundation

class User: NSObject {
    @objc var name: String!
    @objc var email: String!
}

let dictionaryOfUsers = [
    ["name": "name1", "email": "name1@xyz.com"],
    ["name": "name2", "email": "name2@gmail.com"]
]

var users = [User]()
for dictionary in dictionaryOfUsers {
    let user = User()
    user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary) 
    users.append(user)
}
```

Comment: I want to pass dictionary as single object to the method instead of passing key value pair func setValuesForKeys( _ keyedValues : [String : Any])

Comment: @AshimDahal I believe this is what you are after. The `[String: Any]` type is just syntax sugar for `Dictionary<String, Any>`. If this still doesn’t work please improve your question, showing more code, so we can help you further.

Comment: @AshimDahal just occurred to me that there is another (elegant!) solution using Swift 4, structs, and without keypaths ;) Gonna try to post it later today if I have time...

Comment: any other way you think you could solve this problem?@@PauloMattos

Comment: Hey @AshimDahal, what issues are you having with the current solution?

Comment: Its bulky, I wish If there is any short solution, I didn't want to use loops for accessing value in DictionalryOfUsers.

Comment: One thing I could find is that If your object model is @objc compliance. then you could directly use.     user.setValuesForKeys(dictionaryOfUsers). Instead of running through loops

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are trying to use Cocoa key-value coding — which is what `setValuesForKeys(_:)` comes from — on a *struct*. You can't do that. Cocoa is Objective-C; Objective-C has no idea what a Cocoa struct is. You need `User` to be an `@objc` class derived from NSObject, and all its properties need to be exposed as `@objc` as well.

Alternatively, use the new Swift 4 keypaths feature, which can access a struct property by its key. Example:

```
struct User {
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
}

let arrayOfDicts = [
    [\User.name: "name1", \User.email : "name1@xyz.com"],
    [\User.name : "name2", \User.email : "name2@gmail.com"]
]

for d in arrayOfDicts {
    var user = User()
    for key in d.keys {
        user[keyPath:key] = d[key]!
    }
    print(user)
}
/*
 User(name: Optional("name1"), email: Optional("name1@xyz.com"))
 User(name: Optional("name2"), email: Optional("name2@gmail.com"))
*/
```

Comment: this gave me the error "Type has no subscript members"

Comment: @fullMoon then you didn't do what I said. Copy and paste the code in my answer into a Swift 4 project and run it. It works. (A typical mistake is that you misspell `keyPath`, for example. But that's not _my_ fault. I spelled it right.)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this 10 times! I added the `@objc` before all my variables, and voilà! That's the ticket! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to say that Swift 4 has no setValuesForKeysWithDictionary method. Also, the current setValuesForKeys method is often failed in Swift 4 at the latest Xcode version.

My user object is as follow.

```
import UIKit

class User: NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
}
```

My own solution to this problem is to add manually keys as NSDictionary as follow.

```
let user = User()
user.email = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["email"] as? String ?? ""
user.name = (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)?["name"] as? String ?? ""
print(user.email as Any)
print(user.name as Any)
```

It works without any failure. Just try it.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something. In case it helps...
P.S : Please optimise it using generics.

```
  import Foundation
  import CoreData

   enum ModelInitializationResult {
   case none
   case completedWithoutErrors
   case completedWithNullDataErrors
   case completedWithNoSuchKeyErrors
    }

 extension NSManagedObject {

 //Note: For this to work, the keys in the dictionary should be same as attibute name of this class
func initializeModelFromDictionary(dictionary: [String:Any] )  -> ModelInitializationResult{
  var completionResult = ModelInitializationResult.none

  let modelAttributes = self.entity.attributesByName
  let modelAttributeKeys = modelAttributes.keys

  for case let (keyToSet, valueToSet) in dictionary {
    //check for invalid key
      guard modelAttributeKeys.contains(keyToSet) else{
          completionResult = .completedWithNoSuchKeyErrors
          continue;
      }

      //check valueToSetType for Null
      let valueToSetType = type(of: valueToSet)
      guard valueToSetType != NSNull.self else{
          print("ERROR: Found NSNUll for value to set")
          completionResult = .completedWithNullDataErrors
          continue;
      }

      //Check desiredType ; set value for defined types
      let modelAttributeValue = modelAttributes[keyToSet]
      let modelAttributeType = modelAttributeValue?.attributeType

    switch (modelAttributeType!) {
      case .undefinedAttributeType :
          print("Error : undefinedAttributeType")
      case .integer16AttributeType, .integer32AttributeType, .integer64AttributeType :
          if let anInt = valueToSet as? Int{
              self.setValue(anInt, forKey: keyToSet)
          }
          else{
              //print(Pretty//printedFunction(),"Error  in setting value for key:\(keyToSet) Incompatible type")
          }
      case .stringAttributeType :
          if let anString = valueToSet as? String{
              self.setValue(anString, forKey: keyToSet)
          }
          else{
              //print(Pretty//printedFunction(),"Error  in setting value for key:\(keyToSet) Incompatible type")
          }
      case .booleanAttributeType :
          if let aBool = valueToSet as? Bool{
              self.setValue(aBool, forKey: keyToSet)
          }
          else{
              //print(Pretty//printedFunction(),"Error  in setting value for key:\(keyToSet) Incompatible type")
          }
      case .dateAttributeType :
          if let aDate = valueToSet as? Date{
              self.setValue(aDate, forKey: keyToSet)
          }
          else{
              //print(Pretty//printedFunction(),"Error  in setting value for key:\(keyToSet) Incompatible type")
          }
      case .binaryDataAttributeType :
          if let aData = valueToSet as? Data{
              self.setValue(aData, forKey: keyToSet)
          }
          else{
              //print(Pretty//printedFunction(),"Error  in setting value for key:\(keyToSet) Incompatible type")
          }

      case .transformableAttributeType :// If your attribute is of NSTransformableAttributeType,
          //print(Pretty//printedFunction(), "desiredType : transformableAttributeType")
          if let anObject = valueToSet as? NSObject {
              self.setValue(anObject, forKey: keyToSet)
          }
          else{
              //print(Pretty//printedFunction(),"Error  in setting value for key:\(keyToSet) Incompatible type")
          }

      case .doubleAttributeType :
          //print(Pretty//printedFunction(), "desiredType : doubleAttributeType")
          if let anObject = valueToSet as? Double {
              self.setValue(anObject, forKey: keyToSet)
          }
          else{
              //print(Pretty//printedFunction(),"Error  in setting value for key:\(keyToSet) Incompatible type")
          }
      case .floatAttributeType :
          //print(Pretty//printedFunction(), "desiredType : floatAttributeType")
          if let anObject = valueToSet as? Float {
              self.setValue(anObject, forKey: keyToSet)
          }
          else{
              //print(Pretty//printedFunction(),"Error  in setting value for key:\(keyToSet) Incompatible type")
          }
      case .decimalAttributeType :
          print("Error: Data type decimalAttributeType Not handled\(String(describing: modelAttributeType))")
      case .objectIDAttributeType:
          print("Error: Data type transformableAttributeType Not handled\(String(describing: modelAttributeType))")
      default :
          print("ERROR : \(String(describing: modelAttributeType))")
      }
  }
  return completionResult
}

func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]     {
    let keys = Array(self.entity.attributesByName.keys)
    let dict = self.dictionaryWithValues(forKeys: keys)
    return dict
}

func printAllValues (){
    for key in self.entity.attributesByName.keys{
        let value: Any? = self.value(forKey: key)
        print("\(key) = \(String(describing: value))")
    }
}
```

}